# 16.10 dnsmasqd snap wont start as a daemon

Tags: 16.10, snap

I'm new to snaps, so apologies in advance if this is a stoopid Q.

I've installed the dnsmasqd snap and set up the dnsmasq.conf as instructed on https://github.com/lool/dnsmasq-snap

If I invoke dnsmasq from the command line, it works correctly.  All results are exactly as expected.  However, if I attempt to start the snap as a daemon from the command-line or through systemd, I get a permission error writing /var/run/dnsmasq.pid.  From the command-line (as root):

```
# /snap/bin/dnsmasqd.dnsmasq -C /var/snap/dnsmasqd/common/dnsmasq.conf

dnsmasq: failed to open pidfile /var/run/dnsmasq.pid: Permission denied
```

The systemd snap output shows a similar error

```
snap[1330]: dnsmasq: failed to open pidfile /var/run/dnsmasq.pid: Permission denied
```

I've also tried forcing user/group dnsmasq.conf, but no change.

Normally, I can crack permissions issues, but this one is giving me grief.  What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running in classic mode, applications started by snapd is not allowed to read/write/modify files outside of its cage.
You can specify the pid file creation inside the jail ($SNAP_DATA e.g. /var/snap/dnsmasqd/current/dnsmasq.pid) with -x or --pid-file option. See man dnsmasq.